# rsync recursively to a flat destination

Tags: rsync

I would like to run an rsync on an unknown directory structure and have it sync only the files and not the directories.

I have tried numerous ways even including piping a find but with no success.

example source dir:

```
somedir/
   file1.txt
   file2.txt
     anotherdir/
        file3.txt
```

example destination dir:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `rsync` in non-recursive mode (without `-r`) together with recursive shell globs. That way you give it a list of all the files and subdirectories in your folder as arguments, but it will ignore all the directories and only transfer files.

Note: recursive globs (`**`) require the `globstar` shell option to be set in Bash. Enable it for the current session with `shopt -s globstar` or uncomment that line in your `.bashrc` file to enable it permanently.

```bsh
$ tree .
.
└── somedir
    ├── anotherdir
    │   └── file3.txt
    ├── file1.txt
    └── file2.txt

$ rsync ** myserver:/tmp/rsynctest
skipping directory somedir
skipping directory anotherdir

$ ssh myserver tree /tmp/rsynctest
/tmp/rsynctest
├── file1.txt
├── file2.txt
└── file3.txt
```

If you want to specify other arguments to `rsync` that imply recursion (like e.g. `-a`), you can explicitly disable recursion again with `--no-r` instead.

The recursive glob can also be part of a longer path or more complex pattern. Just make sure all the files you want are included, any directory will be ignored.

```bsh
$ rsync -avz --no-r somewhere/local/**/*.txt myserver:/tmp/rsynctest/
skipping directory .
skipping directory somedir
skipping directory anotherdir
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt

sent 231 bytes  received 73 bytes  202.67 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

Comment: ``@Byte`` I am running mac bash terminal. I had to brew install bash as I don't think mac bash supports globstar, but when I did, your command ``rsync source/** destination`` worked perfectly.

Comment: @ejnewman Well, the default Mac Bash is an older version, which might not yet support that feature. However, for Mac you should have asked on [apple.se] anyway, as this site is about Ubuntu only, and here it definitely works out of the box. As it solved your problem though, please consider accepting the answer to mark the question as solved. Thanks.